# mod_rewrite for specific dynamic pages

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have some old product pages showing up in search for a redesigned site.

The old pages are like this:
www.site.com/mycart/index.php?act=viewProd&productId=34

I have static pages that I want these to go to.

so I want

redirect 301 /mycart/index.php?act=viewProd&productId=34 http://www.site.com/prod-name1

I know I can't do this with "redirect 301" since it is not a static page.

I would like to know the best way to approach this.

I will need to have a rule for each redirect since there is no correlation between old structure and new pages.

would it be possible maybe to just match on productId=34

RewriteRule [url contains productId=34] http://www.site.com/prod-name1? [R=301, L]

If that would be a valid solution, how would I go about matching on "productId=34".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you plan to make mod_rewrite understand wich product id relates to each product name?

Comment: That part is already handled within the CMS.  

This was a different cart solution, and there are a few products that I wanted to redirect from the old CMS to the corresponding pages on the new CMS.

So to make it clear, I only want to know how to do what I mentioned above.  What happens after you get to www.site.com/prod-name1 is already handled by the CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond` to test the query:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(&[^&]*)*productId=34(&|$)
RewriteRule ^mycart/index\.php$ /prod-name1? [L,R=301]
```

The `^(&[^&]*)*` before and `(&|$)` after `productId=34` is just to only rewrite if `productId=34` is a complete URL argument and not just part of one like `productId=34567` or `foobarproductId=34`.

Comment: I ended up using this (Before I saw your answer):
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*productId=34.*
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/view/product-name?

I feel that your solution is more robust, and maybe slightly more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to use a 301 in this case? Here's a tutorial on [changing dynamic URLs to static URLs](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/6079.htm). If you are truly redirecting to static pages, you want an external redirect. If you are keeping your PHP files, and want to put a pretty URL in front of it, you want to do an internal rewrite, i.e. when the request comes in for /prod-name-1, route it internally to /mycart/index.php?productId=34, but don't send a 301.

Comment: Please re-read the above comments.   I do want to use a 301 redirect.

I would prefer to just use redirect 301 oldpage http://www.newsite.com/product-name 

But unfortunately, the old cart structure got dynamic pages indexed with ? marks in the urls, and apache redirect won't handle those.